# "We can't let Cardinal Law get wind of this until we know what we have."

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context

"We can't let Cardinal Law get wind of this until we know what we **have**."

This is from the movie called "Spotlight", which deals with the sexual harassment the priests committed on boys. One journalist said "We can't let Cardinal Law get wind of this until we know what we **have**." From what I understood he doesn't want Cardinal Law to know what they're trying to investigate. What I want to know is the meaning "have". What does it mean by "have" as in "as we know what we **have**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**what we have**

The reporters in the movie have some things. They have some leads, some documents, etc. But in a sense they don't know if they have a small local story, a big regional story or a large national or international story.

So they don't want to let Cardinal Law know anything until they know which category the thing they have falls into.

Comment: Ah I got it. I appreciate your help!

Comment: If this was helpful please upvote it (up arrow at the right of the answer) and accept it (click on the tickmark by the answer).

Comment: Oh I didn't know this function. I just did what you said.